# Метод ceil округляет целые числа типа double

Tags: php

Всем добрый день.

Версия PHP 5.6.37

Есть такой код

```
$n = ceil(99 * ((10 / 100) * (10 / 100)));
```

в ходе расчетов получаем просто 1

но ceil округляет его до 2

я понимаю что тип полученный в ходе расчетов double и возможно с этим связан данный баг, но к примеру такой вот код

```
$n = ceil((double)1.00);
```

или такой

```
$n = ceil(100 * 0.01);
```

работает как надо и возвращает 1.

Если ли какие ни будь идеи почему это происходит? И можно ли как то это пофиксить?

Comment: PHP 5.6.36 — `echo ceil(99 * ((10 / 100) * (10 / 100)))` выводит ровно 1

Comment: Обновился до PHP 5.6.37 — по-прежнему выводит ровно 1, вашу проблему воспроизвести не удалось

Comment: Интереснее было бы взглянуть на неокруглённый результат и на результаты выражений в скобках. Что на вашей платформе получается до округления?

Comment: Извиняюсь за неточность в вопросе у меня при 99 тоже все хорошо и выводит как нужно, а вот при 100 уже получаем 1 а выводит 2
Вот пример распечатанный уже в php-консоле битрикса
https://yadi.sk/i/7XkuxAbWzFJIeg
Вот вопрос в ходе расчетов 100 * ((10 / 100) * (10 / 100)) у нас выходит 1 но округляет ceil его до 2 почему ? и как это пофиксить ?

Answer (score 1):

Попробуй выполнить код

`$n = 100 * ((10 / 100) * (10 / 100));
printf("%.18f\n",$n);`

И посмотрите результат.

У Вас число с плавающей запятой, а такие числа не могут точно представлять все рациональные числа. Поэтому результат целочисленного преобразования всегда имеет неопределенность в отношении одной единицы.

Comment: спасибо, я так и думал, просто не знал как вывести `$n` что бы отобразить точные вычисления. Накостылял такую функцию нормально ли использовать такое в продакшене     
`function ceilCustom($n){
 return preg_match('/\.[0-9]+/', (string)$n) ? ceil($n) : $n;
}`

Comment: Можно просто оставлять число float с двумя символами после запятой например, sprintf('%0.2f', $n), и после этого делать ceil. Смотря какая у Вас задача стоит.